# Mysqldump subset of database with relational data using a master table

Tags: backup, migration, mysqldump, relations

I have found a lot of articles describing the concept of exporting and importing relational data, but I have not been able to find any article describing this more generally for a MySQL database, which is why I am creating this question.

### Problem:

I am interested in doing three operations:

1. Exporting a subset of my database (including relations)
2. Removing a subset of my database (including relations)
3. Importing a subset of my database (including relations)

The subset can then be inserted into another database (while maintaining the relationships) or can be kept as backup if the subset is also deleted from the main database.

### Datebase

Imagine the following setup:

- A **master** has one **slave** and one **cook**.
- The **cook** can have multiple **assistants**.
- All people have one **peopleproperty** associated with them.

The Schema can be seen here:
[image: MySQL Schema of database. Illustrating the relations.]

### Question:

How can I export, delete and import a subset of **masters** where id<1000, including their **slaves**, their **cooks** and the cooks **assistants**.

The **peopleproperty** table is small and will be identical on all databases (the live database containing a lot of data, the development database containing some of the data, and the backup database containing all historical data).

### Database Scheme:

Here is he database scheme if needed:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`cook`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`cook` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `cookfield` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `master_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `userproperty_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_user_master_idx` (`master_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_user_userproperty1_idx` (`userproperty_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_master`
    FOREIGN KEY (`master_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`master` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_userproperty1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userproperty_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`peopleproperty` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`assistant`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`assistant` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `assistantfield` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cook_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_assistant_cook1_idx` (`cook_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_assistant_cook1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cook_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`cook` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`peopleproperty`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`peopleproperty` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `peoplepropertyfield` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `assistant_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_peopleproperty_assistant1_idx` (`assistant_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_peopleproperty_assistant1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`assistant_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`assistant` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`master`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`master` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `masterfield` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `peopleproperty_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_master_peopleproperty1_idx` (`peopleproperty_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_master_peopleproperty1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`peopleproperty_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`peopleproperty` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`slave`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`slave` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `slavefield` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `peopleproperty_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `master_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_slave_peopleproperty1_idx` (`peopleproperty_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_slave_master1_idx` (`master_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_slave_peopleproperty1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`peopleproperty_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`peopleproperty` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_slave_master1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`master_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`master` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: You should also check out https://github.com/TonicAI/condenser which just added support for mySQL. If you're curious about how the subsetting algorithm works, you can find additional details here: https://www.tonic.ai/post/condenser-v2/

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Jailer subsetting tool](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/). It's for dumping subsets of relational data, keeping referential integrity.

Comment: This looks like a good tool, but I would like to understand the basic logic behind the SQL operations it's performing.